# References for crystal bases and Demazure modules in representation theory

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory

I was wondering what are some standard general references/books/survey articles about: (1) crystal bases, and string parameterizations and (2) Demazure modules, and Schubert varieties (containing basic definitions and proofs of most of the basic statements). I need to cite some general references on these subjects in a paper of mine.

Comment: This is really a broad question (and needs more tags such as rt.representation-theory and reference-request).  There are lots of sources but with different emphases.   For instance, Hong-Kang, *Introduction to Quantum Groups and Crystal Bases*, GSM 42, AMS, 2002.  And a relevant book by Kumar, etc.

Comment: Many thanks @JimHumphreys for the two references.

Comment: That's a good question! See Mason's paper, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10801-008-0133-4
where she works out the combinatorics for Demazure characters, using skyline fillings. The crystal operators are quite easy to do on these.